# Tangent Plane Approximation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm trying to derive the equation $\Delta z=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}{\Delta x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} {\Delta y}$if $z=f(x,y)$

If I take $y$=cosntant=$y_o$ and vary $x$ I get a tangent line in the plane parallel to the $xz$ plane
that can be written as :

$$
     \begin{aligned}
     z &=z_o+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x-x_o) \\
     y &=y_o \\
    \end{aligned}
   $$
If I take $x$=cosntant=$x_o$ and vary $y$ I get a tangent line in the plane parallel to the $yz$ plane
that can be written as :

$$
     \begin{aligned}
     z &=z_o+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y-y_o) \\
     x &=x_o \\
    \end{aligned}
   $$

If I take the parametric equation for the two lines and derive vectors along the line I get :

$v1=<x_o+t_1,y_o,z_o+at_1>$ considering $a=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

$v2=<x_o,y_o+t_2,z_o+bt_2>$ considering $b=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

$(x_o,y_o,z_o)$ is the point of intersection for the two lines

Is this correct?

I know I can take the cross product of the two vectors to get the equation of the plane but somehow it is not working out
Do I take $t_1=t_2=t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $v1$ and $v2$ are the position vectors of the parametric equations but **not** the tangent vectors along parametric curves.  You can differentiate $v1$ w.r.t. $t_1$ and $v2$ w.r.t. $t_2$ to obtain the tangent vectors.  But the notations you are using are quite tedious, so I would reconstruct your idea as follows:

Let $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,f(x,y))$ be the position vector in the graph of $f(x,y)$.  The vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ along the **parameters** $x$ and $y$ should be:

$
\mathbf{v}_1=\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
{\partial f\over \partial x}
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\mathbf{v}_2=\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
{\partial f\over \partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
$

So the normal vector of the surface $f(x,y) $ would be equal to $\mathbf{v}_1 \times \mathbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-{\partial f\over \partial x} \\
-{\partial f\over \partial y} \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$.  With the normal vector, you can easily derive the plane equation.